# How I can set params in react-router-dom with dynamic import

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have read the documentation  by Tyler Macginnis [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy), but I cand find the solution for my problem.

Basically I was tried to test my routing with custom pages (:page param), but the console.log only print "path" function

[image]

DynamicImport.js to load dynamically pages

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class DynamicImport extends Component {
    state = {
        component: null
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const { path } = this.props;
        const { default: Component } = await path().then((data) => {
            return data;
        });

        this.setState({ component: <Component {...this.props} /> });
    }

    render() {
        const { component } = this.state;
        return <div>{component || <h1>Loading...</h1>}</div>;
    }
}

DynamicImport.propTypes = {
    path: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export const Top = () => (
    <DynamicImport path={() => import('../../containers/Top')} />
);
export const News = () => (
 <DynamicImport path={() => import('../../containers/News')} />
);
export const Show = () => (
    <DynamicImport path={() => import('../../containers/Show')} />
);
export const Ask = () => (
    <DynamicImport path={() => import('../../containers/Ask')} />
);
```

Routing.js to routing

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Routing.css';

const Routing = () => (
    <div className="navigation">
        <ul className="navigation-nav">
            <li>
                <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
                    Top
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to="/news" activeClassName="active">
                    News
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to="/show" activeClassName="active">
                    Show
                </NavLink>
            </li>
            <li>
                <NavLink to="/ask" activeClassName="active">
                    Ask
                </NavLink>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
);

export default Routing;
```

App.js initial file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routing from './containers/Routing/Routing';
import { Top, News, Show, Ask } from './containers/Routing/DynamicImport';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                    <Routing />
                    <div className="container">
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Top} />
                        <Route path="/top/:page" component={Top} />
                        <Route path="/news/:page" component={News} />
                        <Route path="/show/:page" component={Show} />
                        <Route path="/ask/:page" component={Ask} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

When render Top page and set params in URL, params doesn't exist...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Top extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            stories: []
        };
    }
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log(this.props);

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return <div />;
    }
}

export default Top;
```

That console.log print this...

[image]

what's wrong?

Comment: DId you try to import those before (
export const Ask = () => (
    <DynamicImport path={() => import('../../containers/Ask')} />
);
below import React from 'react';
import Ask from '../../containers/Ask';
....
export const Ask = () => (
    <DynamicImport path={() => <Ask />)} />   ??
    <DynamicImport path={<Ask />} /> ???
);

Comment: Yes, but don't work

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I forgot pass 'props' to...

```
export const Top = (props) => (
    <DynamicImport path={() => import('../../containers/Top')} />
)
```